# On Airbnb website the signup has three sub tabs

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, tabs

I am trying to automate airbnb website and then then signup with google I am perfectly able to handle the first tab when the signup option with google appears but when another subtab for signin with google appears then getting error as Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: handle=null three tabs are appearing when signup with google,how to handle this the google signup is mainly required for wishlisting the location

```
    package Practice;
    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.time.Duration;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    
    public class Airbnb
    {
        public static void main(String[]args) throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("Pathtochromewebdriver");
            ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();
            ops.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ops);
            driver.get("https://www.airbnb.co.in/");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.navigate().forward();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"_176ugpa\"]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //div[@class=\"f1xx50dm dir dir-ltr\"]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"query\"]")).sendKeys("Canada");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"bigsearch-query-location-suggestion-2\"]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class=\"_1gazwvry notranslate\"])[2]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"t1l18xbv dir dir-ltr\"]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.navigate().forward();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/label[2]/div/span")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.navigate().forward();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/button")).click();
            String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
            String subWindowHandler = null;
            String childwindow = null;
    
            Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
            Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    
            }
            driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
    
            // Now you are in the popup window, perform necessary actions here
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
            driver.navigate().forward();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[10]/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/form/button/div")).click();
    
            driver.findElement(By.className("whsOnd zHQkBf")).sendKeys("Mymailideeks");
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Has anyone gone through this ?